# cordova - responsive web design

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

My HTML apps is having almost the same layout on any size mobile device & tablets or PC.
Even font uses to adjust as per the screen size. I can also zoom in & out to my app when I open it in chrome browser

But when I convert this html app to android app using cordova, My android app does not show same flexibility.
Fonts do not fit on screen & I cannot zoom in/out my Android app. Also, app layout does adjust as per screen size.

I have used viewport tag in my HTML app.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

My Cordova source ;---
https://github.com/dinguluer/UiMagician/tree/master/samples/cordova/source/test
Cordova Android app genrated for Android 4.3 :--
https://github.com/dinguluer/UiMagician/tree/master/samples/cordova/samples/Android/4.3/Multiple_multi_houses

Main css file on which layout depends :--
https://github.com/dinguluer/UiMagician/blob/master/samples/cordova/source/test/www/css/multiFloorStyle.css

Am I not following cordova responsive web design standard ?

Do I have to change the dimention in css file as per vw & vh variables of viewport ?
If yes then how to do it for my static css file multiFloorStyle.css ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

for better look and feel, font-size , images use media queries in css then you can get.

```
  <style>
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .facet_sidebar {
      font-size: 1em;
      }
     }
  </style>
```

for zoom issue modify your meta tag, your made it user scalable false , thats why its not zooming
     use this:

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; maximum-scale=2; initial-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this max-width will be depend upon the size of the image/font or depend upon width of device ? Being a c++ programmer its getting to much for me.

Comment: it will depend upon the size of device.